# Can we automate sending requests to a web service in SOAP UI window using AutoIT

Tags: soapui, autoit

Can we automate sending requests to a web service in SOAP UI window using AutoIT. AutoIT is unable to identify few controls in the SOAP UI window. The AutoIT Window Info is also not showing any controls details. Please suggest me if there is any other way to automate sending requests to a web service in SOAP UI window?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the tool? Secondly, would you consider sending SOAP messages directly to the web service, without going through the SOAP UI window?

Comment: I have been using the SOAP UI tool to send requests to web service. What is the way to send SOAP messages directly to web service?

Comment: You'd have to intercept a genuine request using Fiddler. Then you could replicate it by doing this: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/45904-soap-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is another way to automate your requests using the command line:
http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using AutoIt to push the SoapUI gui automatically,

1. try to setup SoapUI projects for your webservices with proper assertions (testing for eg. connectivity, schema compliancy, etc) then
2. now you are ready to think how to automate executing these SoapUI projects. The best source is, as mentioned by gaelperret [is on soapui.org](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html). Basically you have to run {soapui.home}/bin/testrunner.bat with proper parameters.

If you want regression/sanity testing you can setup a Hudson environment to manage scheduled and repeated test cycles. [See my previous answer on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067021/automation-testing-web-services/16210635#16210635).

You can also setup an AutoIt script to execute testrunner.bat.

Comment: I have setup SoapUI project for the web service. Now I am trying to execute it from command line using the 'testrunner.bat' but I am getting following error 'log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: soapui.log (Access is denied)' in the command prompt. I assume the problem is with the write permissions for the folder I have mentioned to log my results into. I gave write permissions to the folder but I am still getting the error. What might be going wrong?

Comment: give a try to run testrunner in admin mode or start testrunner from your user directory

Comment: Thanks @codedad. The problem was solved. The write permissions for the 'soapui.log' file was missing. I gave the write permissions to the concerned files in the SOAPUI/Bin folder and the problem got solved. I am able to run SOAP UI tests from command line but there's another problem now. When I run the tests from SOAP UI window, the requests are successful but when I run from command line, the reports being generated for each testcase is showing me the status as 'UNKNOWN' ie. the status in response is 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'.What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the control details is the ideal way, but at worst, you could maximize the SOAP UI window, then use MouseMove and MouseClick.