# How to use Global Property name in my JSON input request using SoapUI?

Tags: properties, groovy, global, soapui

I have a SoapUI project which contains around 60 plus services. Each service requires some input which will be changed for every execution. So I have created certain Global Properties and assign some values to that properties.

I have to use these properties values in my SoapUI request ( i.e. JSON Format request ).

If it is groovy script means, I will use like this.

String HTiC_Username = com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties['HTiC_Username'].value;

But, how to get the value of the Global Property in the request?

Hope you understand my question. Please provide proper guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

To dynamically "expand" (i.e. substitute) the value of a property into a test step, the following syntax is used: `${#scope#propertyName}`

...where 'scope' refers to the level at which the property has been defined (e.g. `Global`, `Project`, `TestSuite`, `TestCase`).

So to expand a property named *username* defined as a *Global* property, for example, the following code can be used directly within a Request Test Step (e.g within a JSON body, or header value, etc):

```
${#Global#username}
```

To access the same property value within a Groovy Test Step, you can use the following syntax:
`context.expand('${#scope#propertyName}')`

...as in the following example:

```
context.expand('${#Global#username}')
```

Answer (score 2):

What we did was the following:

- created a test data file to store all the specific input data for the different services (testdata.properties)

**Example content of testdata.properties:**

> Billing_customerID=1234567
>
> OtherService_paymentid=12121212
>
> ....

- create a SoupUi global parameter (File/Preferences/Global properties): **testdata_filepath**=C:\...
- For specific services we added a **Properties** test step. You can specify the "Load from" field to our new global parameter: **${#Global#testdata_filepath}**   Now you can use the Load button to load parameters.
- Finally you can reference the parameter in your xml in the following format: **${Properties#Billing_customerID}**

**Example content of a service with parameter:**

```
...
<BillingCustomerIdentification>
     <BillingCustomerID>${#Properties#Billing_customerID}</BillingCustomerID>
</BillingCustomerIdentification>
...
```

To set up your projects in this manner also helps to automate service tests eg. using Hudson ([see my previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067021/automation-testing-web-services/16210635#16210635)).

If it is too heavy and automation is not a target, you can simply use **${#Global#someinputvariable}**  format in your xml ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't see Menu -> Prepreferences -> Global Settings option in my SoapUI tool. Currently, I'm using SoapUI Pro 4.5.0.